# Formula help on IF ELSE on Smartsheet

Tags: if-statement, smartsheet-api

I want to have a condition where IF Delivered column checkbox is checked, then that whole row will be deleted. Is that feasible?

How can I start with it?

[image: See the screenshot]

Comment: What happens if the user clicks it by mistake and it gets deleted? How do they get it back?

Comment: What happens if the user clicks it by mistake and it gets deleted? How do they get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this might be possible. If you set up a default filter on a sheet to always load rows where complete box is unchecked, then, if you checked off a task or two and reloaded the sheet those tasks would not be visible the next time it loads.

To do this:

Create a new filter.
Title it and check the Share Filter checkbox
Set the criteria to the checkbox is unchecked
Then click okay
Save the sheet to save the shared filter. 
Click on SHARE
Scroll down and click edit next to the default view
Set the filter to new filter you saved
Save. 
Check off some boxes and save the sheet. 
Reload the sheet and the completed items will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas can't change the condition of an item (like a row), only the value in a cell. So, in other words, you can't delete a row with a formula.

You "could" do this with an external script using the [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/), but you'll want to take situations that @Ken White mentioned in the comments into account. Your script should make sure that there is a way for users to recover the deleted row if the box is checked by mistake.